# Use of Jackson: get duplicated fields in json string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) annotations:

```
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Then I created a `Person` instance & parse it to json string:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstName("John");
p.setLastName("Smith");

//parse to json string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String personJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
```

But the json string (`personJson`) I got is the following:

```
{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}
```

Why I get duplicated fields "`first_name`" & "`firstName`", so to "`last_name`" & "`lastName`" in JSON string?

**===== UPDATE ===**

I also tried :

Annotation:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```

ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
```

But I still get the duplicated attributes in JSON in some other POJO...

Comment: Tested this code with Jackson 2.3.2 - the output is `{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}`. By the way, the jackson has moved to [github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the problem myself.

The reason why I still got duplicated fields in JSON after the UPDATE is that there are boolean properties in my other POJO which yields the accessor methods starting with "**is**" , 
e.g.:

```
public class Other {
   @JsonProperty("money_paid")
   private boolean moneyPaid;

   public boolean isMoneyPaid() {
    return moneyPaid;
   } 
   ... 
}
```

So, the generated json contained {money_paid:true, moneyPaid:true}. To get rid of it, I just added one more restriction on `mapper` when `setVisibilityChecker`, which is:

```
.withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```